# Шерон-мисс/Шэрон-мисс

Tags: орфография

Как правильно ваше имя писать по-русски — *Шерон* или *Шэрон*? Дело в том, что, если в соответствии с РАН, надо писать *Шерон*, т. к. там написаны все случаи написания *э* после шипящих, и только китайские имена входят в эту группчонку, а ваше — не китайское.

Comment: Если вы про Sharon, «Шарон» должно быть. В переводчике, к слову, так и написано.

Comment: Шерон, Шэрон, Шарон, выбирайте, что нравится.  Я подружку в письмах Шерон называла, она вроде не возражала. 
 Это же имя, а для имен общие правила не подходят.  Просто немного непривычно видеть сочетание ШЭ, поэтому Шерон больше нравится.  На форуме тоже на все отзываюсь, просто латиницей писать не всем удобно. https://translate.academic.ru/sharon/en/ru/